# Jenkins-Git Integration issue while connecting to repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to add git repository in Jenkins but it is showing error in the image. I have tried to change git exe, username & passwords but showing same error, while same is working when I am using in Eclipse.

[image: error]

Comment: Jenkins might be trying to access the git repo witha different username/passkey that is not yet registered for read access.

Comment: Tried many times with different username & passkeys but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add SSH key to your jenkins credentials and then use the SSH link of your git repo instead of the https you currently use (assuming your SSH keys are deployed in git).

Not sure where you run your jenkins (if locally or on a server), but if it's on a server, you can try to RDP/SSH to that server and try to do `git clone https:...` and enter your credentials. If that works, you should be able to also get it working in jenkins UI.

Comment: Showing same error when I tried to build Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\Git-2.20.1-64-bit.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Automation" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: